# SVN Lock - Unable to lock file from svn client - Tortoise client

Tags: linux, debian, svn

We have a debian based SVN server with version 1.1.4-2(Pretty Old), When I try to lock a file it shows as below image, Nobody is able to lock any file. Can you please guide me how to solve this issue.I also followed the below client configuration but did not worked. I have attached the error image below.

To configure locking on TortoiseSVN, right-click on any folder and select Tortoise SVN > Settings.... Click the Edit button next to "Subversion configuration file" (tbd: add screenshot). In the Miscellany section, uncomment the following line:

```
enable-auto-props = yes
```

by removing the '#' character at the beginning.In the auto-props section further down, add the line

*=svn:needs-lock

This will specify that locking be applied to all files. See other examples in the auto-props section of the configuration file if you want to apply locking to only a subset of files.
[edit]
Applying properties

If the above client configuration is performed before any files are added, all files will be under the locking policy. However, if there are already existing files in a repository that require locking, they must have the svn:needs-lock property applied. To add the property to all existing files using TortoiseSVN, right-click on the root folder of a repository's local working directory. Select TortoiseSVN > properties. Add the svn:needs-lock property, and apply it recursively. Click OK.

[image]

**Is there anything that we need to add or change. Please help us.**

Comment: The server is rejecting the `LOCK` method - can you provide its configuration?  The `svn:needs-lock` property has nothing to do with whether or not you're allowed to lock a file.  And what do you need locking for, anyway?  Merging is your friend!

Comment: Hey, Also heard that svn lock is not available in the version 1.1.4 as per this link http://www.svnforum.org/archive/index.php/t-31976.html

SVN Lock is available only in 1.2 and later version :-(

Answer (score 0):

Does this problem also occur with other svn clients, such as debian's? Does it happen with ALL files in the repository?

I have noticed the occasional issue with windows and svn where a file locally would have an uppercase character and the same file in the repository did not. It would work on the local computer but the svn server would refuse it because it's case sensitive.

Perhaps it's related to a "case mismatch" like that.

Comment: Hey, Also heard that svn lock is not available in the version 1.1.4 as per this link svnforum.org/archive/index.php/t-31976.html SVN Lock is available only in 1.2 and later version :-(